# Is $F_n+F_{n^2+1}$ composite for all odd positive integers $n>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ denote the $n$-th Fibonacci number and define $$f(n)=F_n+F_{n^2+1}$$ for a positive integer $n$. Then , $f(n)$ is prime for $n=1$ and no other $n\le 1\ 000$

In particular , for odd $n>1$ , there seems to be a small prime factor , concrete for odd $n$ with $1<n<10^4$ , $f(n)$ has a prime factor $p\le 2621$

> Can we prove that $f(n)$ is composite for every odd positive integer $n>1$ or can there still be a counterexample ?

I am also interested in a prime of the form $f(n)$ , if the conjecture is true that for odd $n>1$ , $f(n)$ is always composite , we must have $6\mid n$

Comment: If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, the given function is forced even.

Comment: $F_{n^2+1}+F_n=F_{n^2-n+1}F_{n+1}+(F_{n^2-n}+1)F_{n}$

Since $gcd(F_n,F_{n+1})=1$, it is necessary for $gcd(F_{n^2-n}+1,F_{n^2-n+1})=1$ when $F_{n^2+1}+F_n$ is prime.

Comment: @OscarLanzi True, see the last part of my question.

Comment: Just pointing out that these numbers grow so quickly ($\sim e^{cn^2}$) that one would expect a sequence of randomly chosen numbers of approximately that size to contain only finitely many primes.  So there may well be no more primes even if there's no "reason" for this to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, just a comment that would be too long.

I have sieved $n < 10000$ (odd and even) up to $p = 10^{11}$ and the candidates
`[600, 612, 1452, 1740, 2142, 2280, 2358, 2622, 2748, 3468, 3558, 4014, 4134, 4494, 4800, 4878, 5022, 5100, 5652, 6318, 6480, 6552, 6654, 6660, 7176, 7332, 8268, 9132, 9180, 9348, 9438]` remained.
(That means that for all other $n$ I have found (and stored) at least one prime factor less than $10^{11}$).

Some large factors are:
`99946871509` dividing $n=432$,
`80464010707` dividing $n=1950$, and
`61715775619` dividing $n=4968$.

Furthermore, I have verified that $n \in \{ 600, 612, 1452, 1740 \}$ are composite, thus increasing the search bound to all $n < 2142$.

For odd $n < 50000$ the record for highest least prime factor is $n=27135$ with $34303$ as divisor. The second place is shared between $11007$, $23553$, $39681$, and $45567$ with $5779$ as least prime divisor.

---

**UPDATE:** A few records for the highest least prime factor for odd $n$ are:

```
63 379
927 443
1215 1087
1503 2207
2817 2621
11007 5779
27135 34303
118017 59779
449793 119809
2502657 1277209
```

There are no more records for $n \leq 2.73 \cdot 10^7$.
Note that
$$F(2^9) = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 47 \cdot 127 \cdot 1087 \cdot 2207 \cdot 4481 \cdot 34303 \cdot 119809 \cdot 73327699969 \cdot 186812208641 \cdot 4698167634523379875583 \cdot 125960894984050328038716298487435392001$$
has a lot of these records as a prime factor.